# Filing GitHub repositories into folders?

Tags: github, open-source

I have several related GitHub repositories (all owned by my user) which I would like to file together into a folder.

I can't find how on the GitHub UI - but is there some way to make it happen anyway?

Note: We're talking repos in folders, not folders with repos.

Comment: You just mean on your local system? You should be able to cut and paste the whole containing folder of the repo to a new location AFAIK

Comment: @ZachSaucier: No, I mean on GitHub itself. I know how to put folders in other folders on my local system... :-)

Comment: I don't think that's possible on GitHub, unless you (or someone else) writes code to do it.  The GitHub structure is basically user/repo, right?